# Replace a key value of a Hash nested in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an Array (test) with two nested hashes. What am trying to do is replace the Key value ("idea"=>"Hi") of the first hash (thing). But when i run the program it crashes and i haven't got an error message. I have tried a few variations, but the same results so I'm clearly missing a key step.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
test=[thing={"idea"=>"Hi", "dumb"=>"test"}, thing2={"idea"=>"not sure", "dumb"=>"not"}]
puts test [0]

test=[0] [thing] ["idea"]="Bye"
puts test [0]
gets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- quote hash keys,
- use `=>` instead of `=` between hash keys and values,
- put braces around the hashes,
- remove an extra `=` in `test=[0] [thing] ["idea"]`:

```
test = [{'thing' => { 'idea'=>'Hi',         'dumb' => 'test' }},
        {'thing2' => {'idea' => 'not sure', 'dumb' => 'not'}}]
puts test[0] # {"thing"=>{"idea"=>"Hi", "dumb"=>"test"}}
test[0]['thing']['idea']='Bye'
puts test[0] # {"thing"=>{"idea"=>"Bye", "dumb"=>"test"}}
```

---

Also note that your original code as posted gives me an error, contrary to what you observed:

```
test=[thing={"idea"=>"Hi", "dumb"=>"test"}, thing2={"idea"=>"not sure", "dumb"=>"not"}]
puts test [0]

test=[0] [thing] ["idea"]="Bye" # Error: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer (TypeError)
```

This error message should alert you that something wrong is going on with this line (or before). The error may look cryptic. But the proximal cause of it is that `thing` has been assigned to a hash before: `thing={"idea"=>"Hi", "dumb"=>"test"}`. And on this line the interpreter tries to use `thing` hash as an (integer) index into the array `[0]` - and fails to cast hash as integer. Note that the interpreter tries to treat `[0] [thing] ["idea"]="Bye"` as an assignment.

Long story short, make sure the error messages are displayed. Perhaps they are hidden, for example, by redirecting `stderr` to a file or `/dev/null`.

Comment: Hi Timur, thanks for your help! That makes makes sense.

Comment: @Guvna If this answer solves your problem, please **accept** this answer. This will increase both the answerer's and your reputation.